# How are sensors used in Android games?

Tags: android, opengl-es, gyroscope, game-development

How do people create games which make the object move when we turn or rotate our phone in different directions (accelerating a car, for example)?
Do they use readings from the accelerometer and gyroscope or do they use OpenGL in Android?

Comment: They use the sensor readings to control whatever they're using to draw, whether it's 2D, 3D, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are likely using the accelerometer, because it is widely available on a large variety of devices.

You might want to take a look at this tutorial: http://blog.androgames.net/85/android-accelerometer-tutorial/

And here's a demo of the accelerometer feature from Google: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccelerometerPlay/src/com/example/android/accelerometerplay/AccelerometerPlayActivity.html

Comment: Thanx user1032613...its a good example ...but woooo its does a lot of complicated caluclations :) ..will go through and understand the logic .

Comment: Hi , I tried to understand the code in the sample.Its a lot of mathematics involved there and more over lots of hard coding used without any comments .Is there any body who understand that code well?
And @user1032613 that's what i was exactly looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

This example shows a simple calculation for the 3 directions value 
pitch, orientation and azimuth.

```
if(SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, null, AccelerometerValues_last, MagneticFieldValues_last))
{
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, remapR);
SensorManager.getOrientation(remapR, orientationValues);

Matrix.multiplyMV(orientationVector, 0, remapR, 0, sZVector, 0);
pitch = (float) (-Math.atan2(orientationVector[1], orientationVector[2]) * RADIANS_TO_DEGREES);

Matrix.multiplyMV(orientationVector, 0, remapR, 0, sZVector, 0);
orientation = (float) (-Math.atan2(orientationVector[0], orientationVector[1]) * RADIANS_TO_DEGREES);

Matrix.invertM(remapR_inv, 0, remapR, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMV(azimuthVector, 0, remapR_inv, 0, sZVector, 0);
azimuth = (float) (180 + Math.atan2(azimuthVector[0], azimuthVector[1]) * RADIANS_TO_DEGREES);
}
```

The complete code in the article [How to use Android sensors?](http://ibuzzlog.blogspot.tw/2012/08/how-to-use-android-sensors.html). FYI.